# Hover not working after using custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a clone of a website (sidecup family golf), in which i created a custom cursor  after which my hover elements stopped working (for example if i rapidly move my cursor on that element then the hover effect starts showing otherwise it wont).

Here is my code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#cursor {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #95c11e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var crsr = document.querySelector("#cursor");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  crsr.style.left = e.clientX - 10 + "px";
  crsr.style.top = e.clientY - 10 + "px";
});
```

I have tried changing position of my cursor to relative after which my hover started working perfectly fine but then whenever I scroll my custom cursor move away (like the amount of time I'll scroll the cursor go away from its original position or away from my mouse cursor).

Can you guys take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you're adding some html element as custom cursor which is being positioned on top of everything in your page, thus, all the focus os given to that custom cursor element, which is blocking the interaction with any other element.

I suggest you to change the custom css of your cursor to let the pointer-events ignore that element. Something like this:

```css
#cursor {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #95c11e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none; /* Add this line */
}
```

With this, should be enough.

Comment: It's worth noting that `pointer-events` is not standardized, although all major browsers implement it.

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares yea it worked TYSM!